# Change Date Format in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdateformatter

i am really new to Xcode, and i was wanting to know How do i re-format a date from a string in Xcode?

Here is the string format: Year-Month-day

How do i change it to a string in this format: Month-Day-year ?

Like 12-09-2012

Thanks so much!

Comment: A simple run through the apple documentation on `NSDateFormatter` must help here.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

and it shows the following, hope this helps,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:162000];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"formattedDateString: %@", formattedDateString);

  // For US English, the output may be:

  // formattedDateString: 2001-01-02 at 13:00
```

Comment: when i do this, i get Null, on the NSLog? Why?